# QLayout inside of a QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I know that I can add an `Icon` and `Text` to a `QPushButton`, but I am dissatisfied with the layout of them.
Is there a way to add a `QLayout` with whatever controls I want to a `QPushButton`? For example so that I can have an `Icon`, two rows of text and then another icon on the right.

Comment: Have you tried to subclass `QPushButton` and modify the layout of your subclass?

Comment: It's an option, but I was hoping there would be something equivalent to addLayout() since it's just a one-off thing and I didn't want to create a new class just for that one thing.

Comment: You can have 2 rows of text by inserting newlines. QML doesn't work. For more you will have to create your own class.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the only answer to that question would be to derive a class from either:

1) a `QPushButton` class and reimplement the painting routine.

2) a `QLayout` class that meets your needs, and catch the MouseEvents passed to it and handle them directly.  But lower classes can also catch the MousEvents too, and may upsurp your parent class from seeing them, so be careful about what you put into the Layout.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's really ugly...

But if you need it only once and don't want to develop your own widget,
you can paint everything you want into a `QPixmap` and set it as the icon of an ordinary `QPushButton`.